# Accessing EVP_CIPHER_CTX and GCM128_CONTEXT in OpenSSL(SSL_CTX)

Tags: c, struct, openssl, libraries

Is there currently a good way to access the [EVP_CIPHER_CTX](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fbd23b929609c0b2fe22da97ac349fae5a385027/crypto/evp/evp_local.h#L36) and the [GCM128_CONTEXT](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fbd23b929609c0b2fe22da97ac349fae5a385027/include/crypto/modes.h#L119) in openssl 3.1 via the SSL, EVP, ... APIs with an established connection (e.g., via SSL_CTX, SSL_SESSION, etc...)?

My problem is that, if I want to get the `GCM128_CONTEXT`, I have to interface with the [EVP_AES_GCM_CTX](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fbd23b929609c0b2fe22da97ac349fae5a385027/crypto/evp/e_aes.c#L60) first. Which is a problem since this type is only accessible internally and I do not think copying the struct definition would be a clean way to solve this issue. The `GCM128_CONTEXT` is also available to use with non internal code since it is defined in an ["public" header file](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/modes.h). (Public in this case means that it is gets output to the include directory on build, sorry I could not think of a better word) Which is an indication for me, that it could be possibly used without the `EVP_AES_GCM_CTX`.

Maybe a related Issue:

- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8844#issuecomment-487988022

##### Addtional Context

I could not find a good way to get a `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` from a current `SSL_CTX` or `SSL_SESSION` externally, while looking through the Openssl docs. Internally they can be referenced with ssl_local.h. I would appreciate a way without having to rely on internal methods.

The solution for getting `GCM128_CONTEXT` would be to simply copy the struct definition and get the `EVP_AES_GCM_CTX` like this and simply accessing the `GCM128_CONTEXT`:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/fbd23b929609c0b2fe22da97ac349fae5a385027/crypto/evp/e_aes.c#L227

```c
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx; // Get this from somewhere
EVP_AES_GCM_CTX *gctx = (EVP_AES_GCM_CTX *)EVP_CIPHER_CTX_get_cipher_data(ctx);
gctx->gcm; // This is the GCM128_CONTEXT
```

I would expect something along the lines like this:

1. Setup `SSL_CTX` and initiation the SSL connection (Handshake is done)
2. Get the currently used `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`

- if during the handshake we did not choose an AES_GCM mode abort

3. Get the `GCM128_CONTEXT` from the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`

I am fine with writing some internal Openssl code. My main problem is that i do not want to copy the `EVP_AES_GCM_CTX` struct and subsequent definitions.